# Json determine properties

Tags: c#, json.net

So i have an api that returns a list of objects.
The objects might not always have all properties set and i would need to determine which property values was present in Json response.

For example User object, in some cases it can have Firstname set in some cases not so how can i know that without manually going through Json response and checking each individual property name for existence.

An example Json

```
   {
        "id": 250,
        "gender": "M",
         "country_code": "GR",
        "create_datetime": "2018-11-08T17:20:56+0800"
    }
```

And then

```
    {
        "id": 250,
        "create_datetime": "2018-11-08T17:20:56+0800"
    }
```

I use  JsonConvert.DeserializeObject for de-serialization.
Is manual approach is only way ?

Comment: We need examples of the json and what your classes look like.  This scenario should be easily supported with Json.NET but without seeing your attempts we cannot help

Comment: Json.Net will happily deserialize that, so I'm thinking that's not really your question. You say _"i would need to determine which property values was present in Json response"_ so are you asking how tell which properties were set after deserialization?

Comment: Your User class (not object) can have properties in it which are not represented in the JSON.  Nothing will explode or crash.  Your JSON can have properties represented which are not present in the class.  Nothing will explode or crash.  And it is easy to test.

Comment: @stuartd Indeed that is exactly what i want, sorry if my question was not clear.

Comment: Instead of a class deserialize to a Dictionary so you can test for a key

Comment: as i say that is what i am trying to avoid.

Answer (score 1):

In general, the best way I've discovered to check JSON payloads for membership is to deserialize them and examine the contents. In your case:

```
User resp = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<User>(content);
bool userHasFirstName = !string.IsNullOrWhitespace(resp.Firstname);
```

But wait, you may ask, what happens if I have non-nullable fields and they're not present on the payload? To this, I have two responses:

1. Don't have non-nullable fields on anything you expect to deserialize from JSON if you don't know *for sure* that you'll have a value there. Or,
2. Add `[JsonProperty(DefaultValueHandling = DefaultValueHandling.Populate)]` and `[DefaultValue(YOUR_DEFAULT_VALUE)]` attributes to the property

Note that you can always examine the JSON response as a text string and there are libraries that will let you examine the JSON response as an object. What I have provided is the simplest and broadest use case.

Comment: So you proposing to have some default values that i could check against and determine whether or not the values was set? It could work i suppose as all the values i have are null-able.

Comment: @NullReference If all your values are nullable just compare them to `null` and it'll accomplish the same thing. The only time you'd want to use default values is if you had non-nullable property types like `int` or `bool`.

Comment: @NullReference Sorry, I should've made it clear that you only really need to do one of those options, not both.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think `JsonPropertyAttribute` is for your case, you actually need to serialize all properties, but when you need it, you deserialize it, then just want to return a subset to client.

You can return `anonymous json format` for client without strong typing it, especially when you just want to return a subset of a result.

For example, the `user` you get is:

```
var user = new User
{
    Id = "1",
    FirstName = "Foo",
    LastName = "Bar",
    Gender = "None",
    Orders =[{ Id, time,.....}]
};
```

but if you want to return a subset:

```
return Json(new
{
    Id = user?.Id,
    Orders = user?.Orders?.Select(x => x.Id) ?? Enumerable.Empty<int>()
})
```

then client will get:

```
{
  Id: xxx,
  Orders: [1,2,3,4]
}
```